# PHP Checkbox, Unchecked box option

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I was trying to make my checkbox if the checkbox is unchecked, it saves as a blank(Skip to the next) (" ") / tab ("\t") on my .txt file and at least 1box checked. This is my code:

my html

```
<p>Hobbies:
    <input type="checkbox" name="ahobby[]" value="swimming" />Swimming
    <input type="checkbox" name="ahobby[]" value="reading" />Reading
    <input type="checkbox" name="ahobby[]" value="gaming" />Playing Games
</p>
```

and my php

at least 1 box ticked:

> if (  !isset ($_POST["ahobby"]) || empty($_POST["ahobby"]) ) {
>
> ```
>   $err_msg .= "<p>Please select your Hobby</p>";
> ```
>
> }

this following to save checkbox that were not ticked as blank/tab then to the next item

```
$check_ary = array ("swimming", "reading", "gaming");

$h = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($check_ary);$i++) {

    if ($check_ary[$i] == $ahobby[$h]) {

        fwrite($handle, "$ahobby[$h]\t");

        $h++;

    } else { // saves a blank

        fwrite($handle, "\t");

    }

}

// to the next line by using new line
fwrite($handle, "\n");

fclose ($handle);
```

The problem occurs when I did not chose the 3rd checkbox (gaming), it said Undefined offset: 1, if I thicked the 3rd box alone/ 3(gaming) & 1(swimming)/ 3(gaming) &2(reading), there was no problem at all. And instead of creating a new line (\n), it was only creating a new tag.
anyone have some answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may consider putting your code in an if-conditional like this:

```
     $check_ary = array ("swimming", "reading", "gaming");
     $check_empty = 0;

     for ($i = 0; $i < count($check_ary);$i++) {

         if (isset($ahobby[$i])) {

             if ($check_ary[$i] == $ahobby[$i]) {

                fwrite($handle, "{$ahobby[$i]}\t");

             } 
         } else { 
             // Keeps track of the empty checkboxes;
             $check_empty++;                          
         }

         if ($check_empty >= 3) {
               fwrite($handle, "\t");
         }

    }
```

Comment: it works, but the only problem is when I chose only the second and third / chose without the first array (swimming), it will not write the value into my .txt file. Any suggestion? Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: That's because there is a mismatch in the values of the two arrays (viz. ahobby and check_ary) because the indexing of the array `$ahobby` starts from 0 when you start selecting "reading" which is matched with the value of `$check_ary[0]` which holds "swimming" as its value.

Comment: The workaround could be to get the name of the input checkbox value to be indexed in a static manner (viz. `<input type="checkbox" name="ahobby[0]" value="swimming" />Swimming` ahobby[1] for reading and so on)